# Debugging Facebook login page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I save this page as default.aspx when i tried to run this file using visual basic it just show me simple text. it's doesn't show me button also i set my domain name in facebook apps as 'localhost.local' and site url as 'http://localhost.local/' but when i run it generate this url 'localhost:49162/WebSite1/Default.aspx' with simple text as 'login with facebook' 
it is also giving error in this line `<div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>` that class not define.

Comment: hi i am new to facebook app please help me

Comment: The 'class not defined' warning is just to warn you that you don't have a fb-login-button class in your CSS - don't worry about that. It looks like you're failing to load the script from facebook.net - can you verify (e.g. using your browser debug tools or fiddler) that you're actually loading that?

Comment: hi thanks for reply but things are still not working and i don't know how to use browser debug tools or fiddler. Can u tell me also I have put only this file into my project do I need to put any other binary file into my project do i need to download anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
```

You have to login to the [Facebook developers site](http://developers.facebook.com) and create an application.  It gives you an ID, and then you have to put this application ID there.  Also, you have to register your web site with them, otherwise requests will be denied.  This even works for http://localhost debugging.

You can use the JavaScript SDK to login, by calling:

```
FB.login(function(response) { .. });
```

Comment: i have put my app id here 'XXXXXX' but after that it is still giving me same error it is giving me simple text do i need to download any other file from net and put into my binary folder ?